# singalR with windows 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Has anyone gotten signalR to run on Windows 8 or Server 2012? When I browse to the signalr url I recieve the following error:

```
Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[InvalidOperationException: Protocol error: Unknown transport.]
SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +1052
SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context) +746
SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +97
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12551795
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: Do you mean SignalR as a client or as a server?

Comment: This is happening to me in windows 8 and windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR works fine on Windows 8 and Server 2012, your problem does not seem to be specific to the OS.